# Java 17 Reflection issue

Tags: java

Try to call this function to set the private static final value. This reflection code works on Java 11, but does not work for 17.  Hit a no such filed exception error.

```
    public static void setFinalStatic(Field field, Object newValue) throws Exception {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
        field.set(null, newValue);
    }
```

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: modifiers
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2610)
```

I did try --add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED, but not working.

Any solution or work around for this??

Comment: Why are you trying to get the field `modifiers` of the class [`Field`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html)? Which would presumably be an `int`, if it was a field.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Is calling `field.getModifiers()` not work for you?

Comment: I can understand why people are asking what OP tries to accomplish, but there seems something very strange to be going on. `java.lang.reflect.Field.class.getDeclaredFields()` returns an empty array, while `System.out.println(Arrays.stream(java.lang.reflect.Field.class.getFields()).map(Field::getName).toList());` prints out `[PUBLIC, DECLARED]`... [Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/lpX2ZA).

Comment: @armandino just update the code, and that's what I try to do.

Comment: @KevinChuang see the answer from @Antonio Berritto. His approach will do exactly what you need, assuming you add the `--add-opens` arguments.

Answer (score 7):

Java9 broke reflection and as the version number goes up, the breaks get worse. Essentially, accessing non-exported elements of other modules (modules introduced in java 9) does not work without adding a bevy of complicated `--add-opens` lines when starting the java executable. "modules" as a concept did not exist prior to java9, hence, the java8 and below javadoc makes no mention of any of this.

The vast majority of apps and libraries that warn that they do not work on newer JVMs is because of this backwards incompatible change to the JVM.

The solution is one of four options:

1. The usual one: Downgrade to JDK8 or 11.
2. Do the `--add-opens` dance.
3. Do some light hackery using e.g. `Unsafe`. For advanced users only, and note that this is likely to mean near future JVM versions will break again.
4. Figure out a way to do it without having to reflect your way into non-exported parts of other modules. Here, specifically.. just call `field.getModifiers()`.

Comment: What would you suggest for library developers? I have a use case where I may need to modify fields of `record` objects. @Antonio Berritto's solution works, but I'm concerned about portability across JDK vendors (do they use the same field names due to libraries' reliance on these details?).

Comment: The workaround is already 'closed' in the next JDK iteration. You can't modify fields of record objects. Find a way not to do that. I know, I know. "But... can't" is the usual answer. There are no good answers to any of this. There's a reason lots of folks aren't upgrading JDKs: Various very useful libraries are advising that you don't upgrade, because the tools they need to be compatible with newer JDK versions simply do not exist.

Comment: It's unfortunate things are being tightened down this much without viable alternatives. I guess time will tell where this leads us.

Answer (score 6):

It's no more directly possible since version 12, for [this issue](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8210522) .

For the java 17, I've used this workaround:

```
    public static void setFinalStatic(Field field, Object newValue) throws Exception {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Method getDeclaredFields0 = Class.class.getDeclaredMethod("getDeclaredFields0", boolean.class);
        getDeclaredFields0.setAccessible(true);
        Field[] fields = (Field[]) getDeclaredFields0.invoke(Field.class, false);
        Field modifiersField = null;
        for (Field each : fields) {
            if ("modifiers".equals(each.getName())) {
                modifiersField = each;
                break;
            }
        }
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
        field.set(null, newValue);
    }
```

To run, you should add these arguments:

`--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED`

Comment: Thx for your answer, but after I followed the code and the arguments '--add-opens', I got the compiler error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.reflect.Method; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.reflect.Field; ([Ljava.lang.reflect.Method; and [Ljava.lang.reflect.Field; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap') at TestReflection.invoke3(TestReflection.java:55) ...., I used IntelliJ IDE with jbr-17.0.7, also added the arguments into Run configuration. Did I miss something else?

Comment: I tried with 'jbr_jcef-17.0.7-windows-x64-b1000.6,' and the solution worked. Can you tell me what code you have at the point indicated by the exception 'TestReflection.java:55'? Please note that for anonymous modules, there is no need to add anything

Comment: I followed your workaround again, this time, just focused on your code, fortunately, it worked with "jbr-17...".  I apologize for making you spend more time dealing with my own testing issues.